# Preferable Factory method implementation

Tags: design-patterns

I can implement Factory method in following ways:
Approach 1:

```
  class A
  {

  }
  class A1:A
  {

  }

  class A2:A
  {

  }
static class Factory
{
    public static A GetInstance(int i)
    {
        if (i == 1)
            return new A1();
        else if (i == 2)
            return new A2();
        else
            return null;

    }
}
```

Approach 2:

```
class Factory
    {
         abstract A CreateA();
    }
    class Factory1 : Factory
    {
        public A CreateA()
        {
            return new A1();
        }
    }

    class Factory2 : Factory
    {
        public A CreateA()
        {
            return new A1();
        }

    }
```

Which approach is better? 
What are the advantges/disadvantages of the approaches?
Please let me know the best approach.

Comment: try posting on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the first approach, then if you need to create a new type in the future, let's say, `A3`, then you'll need to modify the `GetInstance` method to write the creation code for `A3`. This violates the [Open/closed Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) -

```
public static A GetInstance(int i)
{
    if (i == 1)
        return new A1();
    else if (i == 2)
        return new A2();

    // modification
    else if (i == 3)
        return new A3();

    else
        return null;

}
```

If you follow the second approach, then you won't need to modify your existing code. You could easily incorporate the new type in the following way -

```
class Factory3 : Factory
{
    public A CreateA()
    {
        return new A3();
    }
}
```

This way you don't need to modify your existing codes.

Choose whichever you feel to be appropriate for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

There is no better approach. They serve different purposes.

The first one uses an argument to decide which appropriate subclass instance to return. The caller doesn't know (and care) about the subclasses. He has an int, and wants the appropriate A for this int.

The second one is just a substitute for a constructor, but forces the caller to already know which Subclass he wants to instantiate, and choose the appropriate factory.